# how do I update a csv file to record user selected images implemented with the toggleClass jQuery function?

Tags: html, jquery, css, csv, imagepicker

I have made a page of images which the user can select with the click and toggleClass functions using jQuery. How do I go about updating a csv file to record which of the images were selected by the user? The script I used to make the images selectable are shown below.

```
<script>
    $('img').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('selected'); 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What would go in the csv and how is it represented on the image elements? Do they have unique  identifiers or do you just want the urls?

Comment: @charlietfl The unique identifiers for the images are the file names. So, in the CSV file there would be a column of all of the file names for the images displayed on the page, and there would be a second column with 1s and 0s to represent which ones have been selected or not selected respectively. I currently have the images loaded in using "img src". Maybe I need to assign all of these images with an ID which would be their filenames? I'm not exactly sure I'm new to all of this.

Comment: Setting the id as file name would be a good start...assuming there are no spaces in the names. Element ids can't have spaces. Then are you wanting to download this csv or write to it and save on server? You can create a csv in javascript but can only write to file server side

Comment: @charlietfl The file names do not have spaces so that's good. I want the CSV to be saved locally on my PC not on a server. Preferably I want to update the same file each time instead of making a new CSV file each time, but if that isn't possible then I can settle for a new CSV file being created each time.

Comment: OK well you can make the csv filename the same, then it's just a matter of the manual "Save As" when you do a javascript download. I'll try to quickly throw an example together

Comment: @charlietfl okay thanks I'll wait for that example.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very basic implementation to get you started. Note the download is disabled by the stack snippet environment in this page but there is a jsfiddle link below also where you can test the download using this same code

For a d

```js
$('img').click(function () {
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});

$('#create-csv').click(function () {
  const rows = $('img').map(function () {
      return [this.id, +$(this).hasClass('selected')].join();
    }).get();

  console.log(rows.join('\n'));
  dloadCSV(rows)
});

function dloadCSV(rows) {
  let csvContent = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + rows.join('\n');
  var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.setAttribute('href', encodedUri);
  link.setAttribute('download', 'my_data.csv');
  document.body.appendChild(link); // Required for FF

  link.click();
  link.remove();
}
```

```css
.selected{border:2px solid red;display:inline-block; width:150px; height:100px}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section><button id="create-csv">Create csv</button><br/><br/></section>

<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100" alt="" id="img1">
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100" alt="" id="img2">
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100" alt="" id="img3">
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100" alt="" id="img4">
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100" alt="" id="img5">
```

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0qa1omb8/) to test download

Comment: Thank you so much for your help this really helped a lot! Sorry for the late response. You've already helped a lot but if you have the time I would really appreciate if you can either comment your lines of code as I am still learning and want to understand what's going on or link me to something that can help me understand what is going on in your lines of code. I just need help with the jQuery and js section of your code.

Comment: That goes far beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow answer. Keep in mind this is not a free code writing service or *"how to"* tutorial service